# Website not reachable via my wifi. but reachable via my mobile network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There are two website(i've noticed) that i cannot access when connected to my wifi
https://material.io
https://pub.dev/

both google related.
I can access these sites from both my computer and mobile only if i'm using my mobile network on my phone or using it as hotspot for my laptop.

But can't when i'm using wifi. they just never load.
Every other site loads.

What could i do?

Comment: Have you tried changing your DNS servers?

Comment: What debugging / troubleshooting have you done? In particular, what happens when you try to ping them?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable about networking. i was only able to narrow down the cause being from my particular Wifi network (and my neigbours - we use the same wifi company)
How do i change my DNS server?

Comment: What OS are you using? A simple Google search with your OS should lead you to detailed instructions.

Comment: MacOS. i will try and give feedback